# Как записывать данные в xlsx файл при помощи python 3.10

Tags: python, парсер, excel

Есть простой парсер, задача которого проверять ссылки.
Если ответ 200, то ссылку нужно внести в xlsx файл.
Каждая последующая ссылка должна быть на новой строке - новом ряду файла.
В данном виде, в xlsx файл вписывается только последняя ссылка.

```
import requests
import openpyxl


XL_FILE = 'file.xlsx'


def main():
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    for u in range(1000):
        url = ("https://site.com/page/" + str(u) + ".html")

        r = requests.get(url)

        if r.status_code != 200:
            pass

        else:   
            print(url)
            ws[2][0].value = url

    wb.save(XL_FILE)
    wb.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

print отрабатывает корректно и показывает, что ссылки перебираются и выводятся только с ответом 200.

Как перебрать ряды xlsx файла и в каждый новый вносить новую ссылку с ответом 200?

Comment: `ws[2][0]` - ну это же одна и та же ячейка. Меняйте номер строки, например `ws[2+u][0]`

Comment: Да, спасибо! Так срабатывает, но вписывает не подряд, а через несколько рядов. Получается остаются пустые ряды где ответ не 200.

Comment: А, ну заведите под это дело отдельную переменную и увеличивайте её там же, где записываете в ячейку, после записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняйте номер строки ячейки, в которую вы пишете `url`, например так:

```
    row = 2
    for u in range(1000):
        url = ("https://site.com/page/" + str(u) + ".html")

        r = requests.get(url)

        if r.status_code != 200:
            pass

        else:   
            print(url)
            ws[row][0].value = url
            row += 1
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь все работает как должно!